# MacVim: Turn off anti-aliased fonts with advanced rendering enabled

Tags: vim, fonts, vi, antialiasing, macvim

With MacVim, I use the Monaco font at size 10, which under the standard MacVim config is NOT anti-aliased.  When I turned on Advanced Rendering in MacVim preferences (advanced tab), Monaco 10pt is now anti-aliased, which is not what I want. Is there a way to turn off font anti-aliasing in MacVim?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I just thought to pull up vim help for "guifont". It shows that `:set noantialias` should do the trick.  I've confirmed that this works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `:set noantialias` to set it for both vim and macvim.